# Repartition a USB device using DiskPart

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, disk-partitioning

I would like to repartition a USB drive using DiskPart from a C# application. This seems reasonably simple: I collect data about plugged disks using the Win32_DiskDrive class and then use DiskPart to run a script that will change the partitions. Critical point seems to be that of mapping the entry I select from Win32_DiskDrive to a disk number in DiskPart. For instance, this is the output of DiskPart:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online          100 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online           14 GB      0 B
```

I need to select the disk by its number. But where do I get that number from data retrieved using Win32_DiskDrive? I guess the answer is using the "DeviceID" field, which returns this "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0". The index at the end seems to be the one I need to match the entry from Win32_DiskDrive to the related entry from DiskPart. Is this correct? Critical question is: is there any place in the official docs where this is stated without doubts? I will then format the device so I cannot do anything wrong here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use **uint32 Index;**

> Physical drive number of the given drive. This property is filled by
>   the [**STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968801(v=vs.85).aspx) structure returned from the
>   [**IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560551(v=vs.85).aspx) control code. A value of 0xffffffff
>   indicates that the given drive does not map to a physical drive.

---

about *DiskPart* disk numbers - i not found in documentation clear stating what is disk number mean here. however i look under debugger, how diskpart format line for disk - internal function

```
long ListDiskLine(IVdsDisk *)
```

called for this.

[image]

it used [`IVdsDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381747(v=vs.85).aspx) interface for get disk properties. the [`IVdsDisk::GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381752(v=vs.85).aspx) method called for get [`VDS_DISK_PROP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249553.aspx) structure
and then used *pwszName* member:

> **pwszName**: The null-terminated Unicode name that the operating system uses to identify the disk. If present, a client can use this
>   property to determine the disk's PNP device number. This is the number
>   obtained from the **`DeviceNumber`** member of **`STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER`**
>   (see [MSDN-STRGEDEVNUM]). For a hard disk, this name has the format
>   `\\?\PhysicalDriveN`, where **`N`** signifies the device number of the
>   disk. For a DVD/CD drive, this name has the format `\\?\CdRomN`, where
>   **`N`** signifies the device number of the DVD/CD drive. A client can use this property to identify the disk.

for hard disk used next code for get **N**:

[image]

or if translate this to *c/c++*

```
esi = _wtol(pvdp->pwszName + RTL_NUMBER_OF("\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive") - 1);
```

the `0x22` is `0x11*sizeof(WCHAR)` and exactly 0x11 (17) symbols in `\\?\PhysicalDrive` prefix.

so diskpart retriever `N` from `\\?\PhysicalDriveN` and this is the number
obtained from the **`DeviceNumber`** member of **`STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER`** (so equal to `Win32_DiskDrive.Index`)

and finally `esi` (where stored `N`) used as:

```
StringCchPrintf(sz, 0x400, L"%s Disk %-3lu  %-13.13s  %7s  %7s   %s    %s\r\n", *, esi, ..);
ConsolePrintf(sz);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the question seems to remain. Is there documentation stating that "Index" is the value DiskPart refers to?

Comment: @LucaCarlon - i can not found any documentation which explain what is disk number in *DiskPart* but research show that this is anyway `DeviceNumber` member of `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` - so same as `Win32_DiskDrive.Index`